# Android TextInputEditText.setText does not accept formatArgs

Tags: android

I using Material TextInputEditText instead of EditText. But TextInputEditText has no setText(resId :int, varargs formatArgs:Any!) which is very useful when formatting string by values->strings.xml and EditText have this method.

So i add this extension method to do that:

```
fun TextInputEditText.setText(@StringRes resId:Int, vararg formatArgs:Any ){
   val formattedText = resources.getString(resId, *formatArgs)
   this.setText(formattedText)
}
```

now i can use it like this:

in values->strings.xml:

```
<string name="persian_date_format">%1$d/%2$d/%3$d</string>
```

in layout file:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/d8"
   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d4"
   android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/d8"
   android:hint="@string/hint_text"
   app:boxBackgroundColor="#fff"
   app:endIconMode="clear_text">

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
          android:id="@+id/pick_date"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:imeOptions="actionNext"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:text="@={viewModel.pickDate}" />
​
  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and in fragment i can use this extension method like this :

```
binding.pickDate.setText(R.string.persian_date_format, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: `better solution` how can you determine is it is better, or not?

Comment: You right, some time it's seems better and feel better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `String.format` instead of creating `extension` function. Check below:

```
binding.pickDate.setText(String.format(R.string.persian_date_format, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth))
```